# Load initial files to material ui dropzone

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropdown

I'm trying to load initial images to the material ui dropzone. I have images in base64 format and I want to load them to the dropzone as the initialFiles.

I have tried to implement this as per the following url using the intialFiles option. But still no luck and don't get any errors as well.
https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/examples#initial-file-from-data-url

```js
const url = 'data:image/png;base64,.....';

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const file = new File([blob], "File name");
    this.setState({
      photo: file
    })
  });
```

My Dropzone

```
html
<DropzoneArea
    style={{height: '30px'}}
    maxFileSize={5000000}
    filesLimit={3}
    disabled = {this.state.fromSnaps}
    onChange={this.handlePhotoChange}
    dropzoneText={"Drag and drop the profile image here or click"}
    acceptedFiles={['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/bmp']}
    dropzoneClass={classes.dropZoneCustomClass}
    initialFiles={[this.state.photo]}
/>
```

Appreciate any input to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: I realize that your fetch function is a bit different with the example you provided. In the example they uses `arrayBuffer`, have you tried following it ?